# Reference request of the formula of Green function on compact manifold with no boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, greens-function

I just met a result in Lemma5.1 of [ref1](https://www.math.kit.edu/iana1/lehre/varmeth2022w/media/struwe%20m.,%20tarantello%20g.%20-%20on%20multivortex%20solutions%20in%20chern-simons%20gauge%20theory.pdf) which seems interesting and counterintuitive, it said that on 2-dimension torus $\Omega$, let $G$ be the Green's function to $-\Delta$ on $\Omega$, satisfying $\int_{\Omega} G(x, y) d y=0$ for all $x$. We have
$$
G(x, y)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \ln \frac{1}{|x-y|}+\gamma(x, y),
$$
where $\gamma$, the regular part of $G$, is smooth on $\Omega \times \Omega$. **Here, the $| \cdot |$ is the distance in Euclidean space instead of the distance on the torus**, I was astonished because this is a little bit counterintuitive, so I searched the case for the 2-sphere, in [ref2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.00864.pdf), the authors computed the Green function on 2-sphere and got $$G(r)=-\frac{1}{2 \pi} \log \sin \frac{r}{2}+C,$$
here $r$ is the angle, which is the distance on the sphere, so the $2sin \frac{r}{2}$ is the distance in Euclidean space.

So I began to wonder, is it true that for all Green function to $-\Delta$ on closed surface $\Omega$, the fomula for Green function is $$
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \ln \frac{1}{|x-y|}+\gamma(x, y),
$$
with the $| \cdot |$ being the distance in Euclidean space? Unfortunately, I searched for days and found nothing, I would be very glad if you know something about this!